# Sigma notation with indefinite limits

Tags: summation, interval-arithmetic

I would like to sum over a partial interval:

$$
\sum_{t = -k}^{0}\beta_{k},
$$

where $\beta$ could be any constant (e.g., $\beta = 5$). I want to express an additive sum from $-k$ to $0$. The negative constant in the lower limit is an arbitrary naming convention.

Question:

(1) Is it proper to call the $t$ a "variable" and $-k$ a constant? Should $\beta$ be $t$-subscripted?

- The real "variable" is $t$, which is a dummy variable.
- It is important to show this explicitly as some academic papers like to express outcomes of a linear equation *before* some event. I use the negative subscripts to explicitly denote the periods before exposure to some intervention.

(2) Could someone review what I have tried:

Assuming $\beta = 5$,

$$
\sum_{t = -k}^{0}5 = 5(0 - (-k) + 1) = 5(0 + k + 1) = 5k + 5,
$$

and if $k=3$ (which is an arbitrary subscript), then the solution is:

$$
\sum_{t = -3}^{0}5 = 5(0 - (-3) + 1) = 5(0 + 3 + 1) = 5(4) = 20.
$$

Any thoughts?

Comment: $t$ is typically called the index (variable), hence often the letter $i$ is used instead. Normally you have something dependent on the index variable inside the sum, for example $\sum_{i = -10}^0 i^2$, but here you don't. You can call $k$ a constant or a parameter, that's context-dependent.

Comment: @user66081 Great! I have one other concern. Should the $\beta$ coefficient be $t$-subscripted? For example: $\sum_{t = -k}^{0}\beta_{t}$? I noticed you said "normally" you have something _dependent_ on the index. In my case, it is simply to index the coefficient before some event (e.g., $\beta_{-4}, \beta_{-3}, \beta_{-2}, ..., \beta_{0})$, where $\beta_{t}$ is any constant value. Thoughts?

Comment: Depends on the emphasis. Let's say you squarely decided $k$ days ago to pay no more than $\beta_k$ per day for coffee; then $\sum_{t = -k}^0 \beta_k$ is the max amount spent so far. If you revise the upper limit each day (but possibly end up with the same daily limit) then $\sum_{t = -k} \beta_t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is mathematically correct.

Your answers for both examples are correct and clearly explained.

Someone may ask why do you use the index $k$ in $\beta _k$ if it is a constant.

Comment: Thank you, Mohammad. I use the index $-k$ in an equation because that lower limit is subject to change depending on which dataset I use. I want to show that it can generalize to any vector of data from $-k$ to $0$. For instance, in one model I run there may be $5$ periods "before" some event. In another, there may be $6$ periods before some event. Would that make sense?

Comment: @Tom  Thanks  Tom,  it makes perfect  sense.